# On Ubuntu 16.04 server I am unable to upload large files in Moodle 3.2

Tags: apache2, php, moodle

I have installed Moodle 3.2 on Ubuntu server 16.04. I am not able to upload files bigger than 2 MB . The error I get is:

```
enter code hereThe uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
```

I changed the entry in `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` to `800M`. I also created an `.htaccess` file in Moodle directory with the following entries.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 2097152000
php_value post_max_size 2097152000
php_value max_execution_time 6000
```

In spite of this I am not able to post any files greater than 2 MB in Moodle. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after the change? What's the output of `phpinfo()`?

Comment: 1. While we talk about PHP and Apache2, I think, you have to change `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`. 2. `post_max_size` must be bigger than `upload_max_filesize`. 3. Are you sure that `.htaccess` files are allowed for this virtual host - is there `AllowOverride All` directive for this `<Directory>`?

Comment: Yes I restarted Apache, to make sure later restarted the server.

Comment: @Spas Spasov  Thank you for your help. I changed post_max_size also to 800M and the problem is solved,

Answer (score 1):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size):

> **post_max_size**
>   Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. **To upload large files, this value must be larger than `upload_max_filesize`.** Generally speaking, `memory_limit` should be larger than `post_max_size`.

From [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15077229/6543935) of similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7754133/6543935) in *Stack Overflow*:

> **upload_max_filesize** is the limit of any single file. **post_max_size** is
>   the limit of the entire body of the request, which could include
>   multiple files.
>
> Given `post_max_size = 20M` and `upload_max_filesize = 6M` you could
>   upload up to 3 files of 6M each. If instead `post_max_size = 6M` and
>   `upload_max_filesize = 20M` then you could only upload one 6M file
>   before hitting post_max_size.

By default (in PHP 7.0) the value of **post_max_size** is four times larger than the value of **upload_max_filesize**:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the best place to put the values for Apache is in the Per directory options under PHP..   for the Website needing the values.. It's called PHP configuration values under webmin   or use the site .conf like this
[one of my conf files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeZ5Y.jpg)